# what does subnet 163 specify?

Tags: networking, router, dhcp, subnet, dhcp-server

I just got a new router.  It has the following fields filled in (under the DHCP Server section):

`Range: 192.168`

`Subnet: 163`

`Start: 100`

`End: 250`

What IP range does this specify?

Thanks

Comment: Could you provide a screenshot (image)?

Comment: That seems to be some bad programming in the router. You can't really know the subnet without know the network mask. Assuming the `192.168.0.0/16` network, then `192.168.163.0/24` would actually be the 164th subnet because the first subnet would be `192.168.0.0/24`.

Comment: @RonMaupin : 192.168.163.128/25 would entirely cover 192.168.163.100 through 192.168.163.250. The point of a network mask is to specify a network size. So we ***do*** know this info, since we can determine the size of this address group, because we do have the start address and end address. It looks like this is a size of 151, so not an entire CIDR-specifiable subnet. The technically-correct answer is this range does not specify such a CIDR-specifiable subnet. This is just a group of IP addresses (which is larger than any /26 but smaller than this /25) which is handed out by the DHCP server.

Comment: "_`192.168.163.128/25` would entirely cover `192.168.163.100` through `192.168.163.250`_" No, it would not. It would only cover `192.168.163.128` to `192.168.163.255`. The rest of your comment makes no sense.

Comment: @TOOGAM Without more info, the most likely assumption is `192.168.163.0/24` with a DHCP address pool from `192.168.163.100` to `192.168.163.250` (leaving <.100 and >.250 for static assignments etc.). This is a fairly typical configuration for home routers, though the `163` is odd. That's why I asked for a screenshot - there is technically not enough information here to answer without a fair amount of guesswork, and I suspect some error in the transcription into the question.

Comment: Correct, the 192.168.163.0/24 is the network and DHCP is used between .100 and .250.

Comment: @RonMaupin is quite right.  192.168.163.100-192.168.163.127 are not covered by 192.168.163.128/25, so my first sentence was quite wrong.  I cannot say just why I botched that statement so significantly.  This question has an accepted answer which I see as being right enough to accomplish the expected goals, so I'm currently intending to discontinue trying to further discuss how clear or sufficient the provided details were, realizing this means I will have failed to dig myself out of this hole I created for myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

192.168.163.100-250 another way of reading it 192.168.163.[100-250]

Comment: haha i figured that out just now....